# Using Time in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to change the shape of turtle after specific time. I am weak at code so here is the mechanism in steps: 
1). Turtle 1 attacks Turtle2.
2). turtle2 changes shape after attack to from "Shape1" to "Shape2".
3). turtle2 gain its shape back to "Shape1" after specific time.
4). I would like to use a slider for time duration selection.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow!  Your question could be improved by showing us what you have already tried.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you mean time as in ticks? or time as in seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about ticks.

Essentially, if the ticks is equal to a value, set the shape of the agents you want to something else..If you want to use a slider, replace some-time with the name of the variable...

```
if ticks = some-time [ ask turtle 0 [set shape "dot"]]
```